# Update column with concat subquery result SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, concatenation, sql-update, ssms

I have written the following code to concat myData into one row, based on the StagingNotificationId.  I now want to replace the original newData with the result of my sub query but struggling to do this, any help would be appreciated

```
SELECT StagingNotificationId, newData = 
STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '||' + newData
       FROM #TempTable b 
       WHERE b.StagingNotificationId = a.StagingNotificationId 
      FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') + '||'
FROM #TempTable a
GROUP BY StagingNotificationId
```

Comment: Looks more like MS SQL Server than MySQL - right?

Answer (score 0):

To replace the original `newData` column in your `#TempTable` with the result of your subquery, you can use the `UPDATE` statement. Here's how you can do it:

```
-- Update the newData column in #TempTable
UPDATE a
SET a.newData = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '||' + newData
                      FROM #TempTable b 
                      WHERE b.StagingNotificationId = a.StagingNotificationId 
                      FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') + '||'
FROM #TempTable a;
```

Comment: Thanks, that updates the newData but I need the rows to be grouped by StagingNotificationId.  This returns multiple rows with the same StagingNotificationId